# Бот не выдаёт роль Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord, .net

Я уже третий день пытаюсь найти решение, я пишу бота для Discord-сервера.
На нём есть роль "Обычный житель" ID - 691989517141409792, я получаю её через GetRole(691989517141409792),
и добавляю через AddRoleAsync(НАЗВАНИЕ), но ничего не происходит и роли в Discord нету

```
public Task OnUserJoined(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        SocketRole role=user.Guild.GetRole(691989517141409792);
        user.AddRoleAsync(role);
        user.SendMessageAsync("Добро пожаловать на "+user.Guild.Name);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Comment: А отладку вы проводили? Пройдитесь по порядку и посмотрите, какие переменные имеют не то значение, которое вы ожидаете. И да, где у вас `async/await`? На сколько я понимаю, методы `...Async` должны запускаться при помощи `await` (прим `await SendMessageAsync(...)`).

Comment: спасибо, попробую